# Could not cast value of type 'SKSpriteNode' to myApp.CustomSprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift and SpriteKit so please bear with me.
I'm trying to creating a simple game, I made a custom class (CustomSprite):

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class CustomSprite: SKSpriteNode {

     var spriteColor: String = ""

}
```

CustomSprite has spriteColor for checking reasons only (later in the game)
I'm trying to make a new sprite in the GameScene:

```
var mPlayer: CustomSprite = CustomSprite()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //crashes here (mPlayer = self. xxxxxx)
    mPlayer = self.childNode(withName: "mainPlayer") as! CustomSprite
    mPlayer.spriteColor = "red"
}
```

I get this error when running the game and getting to didMove:

```
Could not cast value of type 'SKSpriteNode' to 'myApp.CustomSprite'
```

I don't understand what I have to do in order to fix it, and why this is happening.
I did set the Custom Class in the `.sks` file to CustomSprite and saved, but it didn't changed or fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to substitute your code with an optional binding:

```
if let sprite = self.childNode(withName: "//mainPlayer") as? CustomSprite {
           mPlayer = sprite
           // do whatever you want with your mPlayer
}
```

The "**//**" before `mainPlayer` specifies that the search should begin at the root node and be performed recursively across the entire node tree. Otherwise, it performs a recursive search from its current position. You can find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74)

Comment: This solution is not working, still getting the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly set to your SKS file (to the file inspector) your custom type related to your mainPlayer?

Comment: Yes, I had the same piece of code that worked(With SKSpriteNode, not CustomSprite), the only difference is that I'm now trying to subclass SKSpriteNode so I can have another value in SKSpriteNode (spriteColor).

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint to the line mPlayer = sprite and to the debugConsole type : po sprite. If the result is NIL your mainPlayer is not in the GameScene.SKS

Comment: It doesn't seems to be null, also, the error is not mentioning anything about null.

Comment: Perfect, very well, what say if you ask to him always in the debugConsole `po type(of:sprite)` or `po sprite.debugDescription`

Comment: Im very sorry for the trouble, I decided to ditch this right now, and fresh start everything. Im really new to SpriteKit and Swift, so I'm still learning. Again, Thank you and sorry for trouble :(.

Comment: You welcome, sometime restart is a good way to make better and strong things. Good luck!